# SqlDataReader returns null on second loop run

Tags: c#, .net

The system is built in .net EF 4.8 and sql server.

when I'm trying to read the next line of data - the data is disappearing and it's become to null.
here's the code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
 {

         //Some parameters are loaded on cmd

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Connection.Open();


   using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
      {
         if (reader.HasRows)
         {
                                
          while (reader.Read())
            { 
              //working with the corrent data
            }
```

for e.g., the DB return 8 lines. the loop works fine with the forst line. the second run of the loop its getting out in the null condition (if the value is equal to null, the loop return null and finish).

The connection to the Database works properly.

how can I keep the data until the software finishes running on all the lines?
I checked other similar questions and did not find a solution that works for me.

Comment: Please elaborate on "the data is disappearing and it's become to null". What becomes null? Do you call `.Read()` again within your `while`?

Comment: The data is being emptied. in the first time I can see (debugger mode)  all the lines , and when I open the data again, its look like No results appear to exist. and no, I'm not using ``` .Read()``` withing the while loop.

Comment: What are "the data" and "the object"? You do realise that reading the data through the debugger exhausts the reader? You can only read it once.

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry, I meant the "reader" object
It happens during the loop run for the first time even when I don't open the data. When it returns to the top of the loop it falls on an instance of Null even though it should be data.

Comment: You keep using terms that don't link to the code shown. Please make sure the code in your question corresponds to your description. What is "it falls on an instance of Null"?

Comment: Also if you are using EF why are you using `SqlDataReader` directly? Side note: `if (reader.HasRows)` is pointless as `reader.Read(0` tells you that

Comment: @CodeCaster "falls on an instance of null" meant that I have a condition of null in the while loop: ```if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Address")))```

Comment: Please just edit your question to contain a [mre]. I can't make chocolate out of this.

Comment: Are you very sure that 'Address' isn't actually null for that second row?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing 100% sure

Comment: The skeleton code you show should just work. If it doesn't, and you need help, you need to make sure the code properly represents your problem. This exact pattern is used in tens of thousands of application all over the world, if not more. The problem is in the code (or data) which you do not show.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can tell you more than that, this code worked fine for years, and the problem suddenly appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

However I would strongly advise not to use the datareader but maybe use an SqlDataAdapter to fill a datatable, which is much more intuitive to use, maybe something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(query, connection)).Fill(dt);
```

Comment: I did in this wey:
`SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();


                        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                        DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

                        int id;

                        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                        { 
//the loop on each row
}
`